# Not able to set SVG as a CSS background image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG that I want to set as a background image for an `input` tag so that I could use an image as a radio button. I've been following many guides but nothing seems to work. I'm suspecting that it has to be the SVG content itself.

Here's the SVG:

```
<svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="473 123 80 80" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="face_sad" opacity="0.8" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(473.000000, 123.000000)">
    <path d="M40,0 C17.90861,-1.3527075e-15 2.705415e-15,17.90861 0,40 C-2.705415e-15,62.09139 17.90861,80 40,80 C62.09139,80 80,62.09139 80,40 C80,29.3913404 75.7857264,19.2171839 68.2842712,11.7157288 C60.7828161,4.21427361 50.6086596,6.49593051e-16 40,0 Z M40,77.6 C19.2340934,77.6 2.4,60.7659066 2.4,40 C2.4,19.2340934 19.2340934,2.4 40,2.4 C60.7659066,2.4 77.6,19.2340934 77.6,40 C77.5779535,60.7567678 60.7567678,77.5779535 40,77.6 L40,77.6 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    <path d="M40,49.2 C27.2,49.2 20.16,59.008 19.408,60.128 C19.1388619,60.481731 19.0872921,60.9552533 19.2739762,61.3586265 C19.4606604,61.7619997 19.8550164,62.0291441 20.2988593,62.0529021 C20.7427021,62.0766601 21.1633224,61.8531397 21.392,61.472 C22.08,60.464 28.408,51.6 40,51.6 C51.592,51.6 57.92,60.464 58.608,61.472 C58.9937796,61.9790342 59.7085433,62.096207 60.2360188,61.7388849 C60.7634943,61.3815628 60.9197839,60.6743215 60.592,60.128 C59.84,59.008 52.8,49.2 40,49.2 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    <ellipse id="Oval" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="29.616" cy="28.8" rx="4" ry="4"></ellipse>
    <ellipse id="Oval" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="50.384" cy="28.8" rx="4" ry="4"></ellipse>
    <path d="M54.76,35.04 C54.6,34.88 54.44,34.8 54.2,34.8 C53.96,34.8 53.8,34.88 53.72,35.04 C53.64,35.12 52.44,36.56 51.16,38.32 C49.48,40.8 48.6,42.72 48.6,43.92 C48.6,46.88 51.08,49.2 54.2,49.2 C57.24,49.2 59.8,46.8 59.8,43.92 C59.8,42.72 58.92,40.88 57.24,38.4 C56.04,36.56 54.76,35.12 54.76,35.04 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and my CSS for the input:

```
input#bad-choice {
  background: url(../assets/img/svgs/emoji-bad.svg);
}
```

I've tried adding thing like `no-repeat left top` in `background` or even changing it to `background-image`, but nothing seems to work. I even tried converting it to data URI but that didn't seem to work neither. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I assume the SVG is actually saved as an image...right?

Comment: a) Have you tried `input { background-image:url('foo.svg') }` instead of `background: url()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539957/how-to-include-svg-file-as-input-background? b) Path correct?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm linking the svg file directly... unless you mean rename the svg as a png?

Comment: @Samuel I have multiple svgs, that are all different, so just selecting `input` wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you testing with a proper webserver, or locally via "file://"?  If the latter then you may be striking Chrome's security restriction on file URLs. Test with another browser.

Comment: Also, what does "nothing seems to work" mean?  The image doesn't appear?  Is it showing in the dev tools? Any errors there?